# if statement mistake on jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

hi there i am working on a jquery ajax solution for my webpage there is a getir.php 
i use it for jquery post data (it is a username) and if name exist it echo 'TRUE' or 'FALSE'

here it is

```
if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
if($synan->checkNameIsExist($_POST['name'])){
    echo'TRUE';
}else{
    echo'FALSE';
}
}
```

it works fine i see true or false results in console but i have problems on jquery part

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#user_name_reg").blur(function () {
        txt = $(this).val();

        $.post("getir.php", {
            name: txt,
            method: "checkName"
        }, function (result) {

            console.log(result);
            if (result == 'TRUE') {
                $("span").html("answer true");
            } else {
                $("span").html("answer false");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

i couldnot make it work the if statement .
thank you for your suggestions

Comment: What actually happens when the code is executed? Do you get a JavaScript error? Do you see "answer false"?

Comment: What if you `console.log("'" + result + "'");`? Do you see whitespace in output?

Comment: Whats the value of result from your log?

Comment: Can you post the output of `console.log(typeof result, result.length, result);`?

Comment: my log is fine i see false and true as it must be

Comment: @synan54 There's obviously something weird going on if you're echo'ing `"TRUE"` and `"FALSE"` but you're seeing `true` and `false` in the console.  The statement I posted will help us diagnose if there's some weird type conversion going on.

Comment: @jmar777 i see in my log when do it like this console.log("'" + result + "'");     'false  or 'true

Comment: @synan54 I'd prefer to ran my suggestion than that one, as the one you used will mask whether or not `true` is a string vs. a boolean.

Comment: Does `getir.php` send a `Content-type` header?

Comment: @jmar777 i see in my log when i do like you said console.log(typeof result, result.length, result);       string

78

true

Comment: @synan54, ahh... definitely a whitespace problem then.  I'll post a relevant answer.

Comment: @synan54 I've posted an answer, I'll add some details.

Comment: @Barmar no it doesnot send a header

Comment: The whitespace problem suggests that the script has a bunch of blanks before `<?php` or after `?>`. Clean that up.

Comment: The part that's still confusing to me is how we went from `"TRUE"` to `"true"`.  Anyway, I posted something that should account for 1) dealing with a string, that 2) has a lot of whitespace, and 3) has some weird case conversion going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that your output from:

```
console.log(typeof result, result.length, result);
```

was `string 78 true`, we know 3 things:

1. We're dealing with a string
2. There's a lot of whitespace involved
3. There's some weird case conversion going on.

The solution below accounts for these observations:

```
result = $.trim(result).toLowerCase();
if (result == 'true') {
    $("span").html("answer true");
} else {
    $("span").html("answer false");
}
```

Comment: yeahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh  it works thanks you man it killed my 1 hour

Comment: The solution is good, but it would be a good idea to work on your PHP script to clean up the output before returning it. Maybe return a standard format such as JSON, and remove the cleanup code from your client-side script, where it doesn't really belong (since you control the backend).

Answer (score 1):

If PHP is using the default content type: 'text/plain' and is really returning just either 'TRUE' or 'FALSE' **without any leading whitespaces or other content surrounding it** the example above **will** work. You should make this sure using quotes around the output when calling `console.log()`. Like this:

```
console.log("'" . result . "'");
```

If there are whitespaces around it, make sure that you have no content before the opening `<?php` tag or after the closing `?>` tag in PHP